# Querying IList using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Is foreach is the only option to get the property values of an object? (if I store that in var type)

```
IList<SampleClass> samples = GetIList();
var onesample = samples.Select(p => p.Propy == "A").FirstOrDefault();
```

do I need to loop through 'onesample' to get the values using foreach or any better way?

Comment: You can't iterate over `onesample` anyway - it's just of type `bool` because you're selecting a sequence of `bool` and then taking the first value. It's really not at *all* clear what you're trying to achieve. (I suspect you meant `Where` rather than `Select`, for one thing.)

Comment: What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: `Select` is for projection, `Where` is for filtering

Comment: @JonSkeet No, onesample is of type SampleClass, not a bool value.

Comment: @oddparity There is no doubt that onesample is a bool value. It seems you also have CoolArchTek's problem.

Comment: @oddparity: What do you believe the return type of `Select(p => p.Propy == "A")` is?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, you are right. Mistook select for where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try with this.

```
IList<SampleClass> samples = GetIList();
SampleClass onesample = samples.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Propy == "A");
```

Comment: IList [has no idea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=net-5.0#methods) about FirstOrDefault().

Answer (score 0):

you dont need select or where ...you can just apply lambda express on the FirstOrDefault

```
 IList<SampleClass> samples = GetIList();
 var onesample = samples.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Propy == "A");
```

Comment: IList [has no idea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=net-5.0#methods) about FirstOrDefault().

Comment: You should import System.linq @z33k

Comment: well, then you should've included it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the OP's question is totally unhelpfully formulated, but in case someone found himself here (as me) because he wanted to use LINQ with IList (one good example is trying to get a selected item inside WPF Combobox's SelectionChanged handler), here's my solution:

Cast `IList` to `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
private void Combobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string item = ((IEnumerable<object>)e.AddedItems).FirstOrDefault() as string;
            Console.WriteLine($"Combo item is: '{item}'");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IList<SampleClass> samples = GetIList();
var onesample = samples.Select(p => p.Propy == "A").FirstOrDefault();
```

Should be..

```
IList<SampleClass> samples = GetIList();
var onesample = samples.Where(p => p.Propy == "A").FirstOrDefault();
```

This will get you one instance of `SampleClass`